# Why won't my second loops execute when the program is run?

Tags: c++, for-loop

First loops runs completely fine but the data is not displayed from the second loop. The program ends after inputting data during the first loop. Am I displaying it wrong? Is the sequence not correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Empinfo
{
string name;
int pay;
double hours;
double gross_pay;
};
int main()
{
int count;
int index;
const int arraysize = 3;
Empinfo employee[arraysize]; 
for (count = 0; count < arraysize; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter name of employee" << " " << (count + 1) << ":";
    cin >> employee[count].name;
    cout << "Enter the hourly pay for " << employee[count].name << ": ";
    cin >> employee[count].pay;
    cout << "Enter how many hours " << employee[count].name << "worked: ";
    cin >> employee[count].hours;
    cout << endl;

}
for (index = 0; index << arraysize; index++)
{
    cout << employee[index].name;
    cout << employee[index].pay;
    cout << employee[index].hours;
    cout << employee[index].gross_pay;

}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `index << arraysize` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (index = 0; index << arraysize; index++)
```

Your condition becomes `0 << 3` which is `0` hence the loop doesn't even run once.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, This sentence:

```
index << arraysize
```

should be:

```
index < arraysize
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second for loop is written incorrectly

```
for (index = 0; index << arraysize; index++){ ... }
```

If you notice you did *index << arraysize* instead of *index < arraysize*

The *<<* and *>>* operators are bit wise operators, which you can read about here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/

Also I have a slight suggestion to improve readability and reduce clutter in your c++ programs, when you declare a for loop with a variable you will not need outside of the loop do so *inline* like this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < arraysize; count++){
//Insert your logic here
}
for (int index = 0; index << arraysize; index++){
//Insert your logic here
}
```

Doing so will let you remove your variable declarations for count and index at the top of your program.

Comment: wow thank you very much. A dumb mistake I looked over. I appreciate your suggestion as well I will keep that in mind for future programs.

Comment: Personally, for readability, I'd go further, and place the two loops in separate functions (say `input_employees()` or `print_employees()`, or some other name you consider clearer in context of your program).    I'd also use a standard container rather than a raw array as well.